# Use of namespaces for separate project / product content pages

Tags: mediawiki

I have a number of apps which I want to write product manual material for with MediaWiki.

I could install a wiki as sub-domain in myorganization.com for each app e.g. **wiki.app.myorganisation.com/wiki/Some_Title** and/or create a WikiFarm with each site having their own *LocalSettings.php* but this seems to get messy quickly with multiple configurations and databases to maintain for each product manual.

Namespaces seem to be the way to go and appear to come with benefits in terms of fine-grained security e.g. users who contribute content for *App1* likely should not be able to contribute content for *App2*.

This would mean a single installation of MediaWiki in **wiki.myorganization.com/wiki/** with manual pages prefixed by the app name and page title e.g. **wiki.myorganization.com/wiki/SomeApp:Some_Title** and **wiki.myorganization.com/wiki/OtherApp:Some_Title**

This would ensure topics / titles like `User_Management` which would need to exist in both app product manuals can co-exist. It would also mean a single central repository for all organisational product knowledge.

Moreover, I am choosing MediaWiki for its API. Ultimately the goal is to be able to present in-line product manual content from MediaWiki in the app itself. I am not sure if separating each app's manual pages into their own namespace present any challenges for querying/retrieving this content?

I would love to hear the thoughts of more experienced MediaWiki users and/or their recommendations.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fact that the number of custom namespaces [is limited](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table#page_namespace) to 9900.

Also note, that there are certain per-namespace *MediaWiki* [settings](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings#Namespaces) in `LocalSettings.php`, including namespace declaration itself. There is the extension [*SpecialNamespaces*](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpecialNamespaces) but is has not been updated since 2009.

I suggest another solution: store all your pages in the main namespace. Group the pages relating to the same product as [subpages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subpages) of the main page describing the product ([enable](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespacesWithSubpages) them for the main namespace).

Limiting access to editing per product can be done by [protecting pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Protecting_and_unprotecting_pages), which is done via web not `LocalSettings.php`, although you will need to define a [protection level](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRestrictionLevels) and a [user group](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgGroupPermissions) per product; but the latter has to be done for namespace protection as well. Though I doubt that you literally have a separate product manager for each product; so you may really need only a few user groups.